# Create a Constants.h and Constants.m file

Tags: xcode

I wanted to create a Constants.h and Constants.m file. I have created the .h file  by right clicking on the File Inspector and then creating a new header file for the Constants.h. But how can I create another file, Constants.m?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a .h file by itself, go to File > New > File, and select "Cocoa Touch Class".

This will create a .h and .m file with the same name, the .h file will have the UIKit framework imported (since its a Cocoa Touch class) and the .m file will have the .h file imported automatically.

[image]

Comment: Yep, then just delete the actual class interface in the `.h` and the implementation in the `.m`.

Answer (score 0):

To create just the .m file

1. In the status bar, go to File --> New
2. Choose Source in the left panel
3. Choose Objective-C FileClick Next on the bottom right
4. Enter a file name and click Next on the bottom right
5. Choose a location and click Create on the bottom right